# Use Google Sheets ImportXML with XPath to import Amazon product title

Tags: xpath, import, google-sheets

I want to get the Product title from an Amazon product page in Google Sheets.

I have searched and tried different approaches and came up with this

=ImportXML("[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01MSR8J29](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MSR8J29)","//*[@id='productTitle']")

I want to get the title:
Army Flag Shirt: Become Brothers Army TShirt

But I get Error, Imported content is empty.

[Demo Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DfLobMp-QKLEL5lrIn2Kx8UYj-fP5G2RqS9N32HcSuY/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 2):

Much of HTML isn't valid XML, in particular Amazon's pages are not valid XML. So, `importXML` fails on them.

You can use an Apps Script via a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) as follows (remove the space before "amazon", it's here to prevent SO from rewriting the URL):

```
=producttitle("https://www. amazon.com/dp/B01MSR8J29")
```

returns "Army Flag Shirt: Become Brothers Army TShirt", provided that the custom function is entered in Script Editor as follows:

```
function productTitle(url) {   
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var match = content.match(/<span id="productTitle".*>([^<]*)<\/span>/);
  return match && match [1] ? match[1] : 'Title not found';
}
```

Here, the first line gets the source of the page; then a regex extracts the item title.

You will find a similar post [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88238), including the question of whether this activity is compliant with Amazon's Terms of Services.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with just the `//title` xpath and a simple regexreplace to remove the standard `Amazon.com:` portion:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(ImportXML("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01MSR8J29","//title"),"Amazon.com: ","")
```

[image]

If you also want to remove the rest of the breadcrumb e.g. `: Clothing` just modify it to use the `OR` symbol which in regex is `|` like this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(ImportXML("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01MSR8J29","//title"),"Amazon.com: |: Clothing","")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works great, I do have a second additional question, I want the Product title to link to a asin from column B and got it working but now i need to get the product title in there somehow, I updated the Demo Sheet to show what i mean.

 If you have time to check it out would be great.

Comment: I added two possibilities to your second question.  They are in the spreadsheet below your sample.  I added a third which uses the ASIN in all possible locations of the formula.  I also tried to use an arrayformula to generate these from a single formula but the IMPORTXML() function doesn't like the array.

Comment: @Karl_S I used the last one and it seems to work, But  for some ASIN codes the text becomes "Robot Check" instead of the product title. Do you know what's up with that? i added one to the demo that does that.

Comment: When I opened the spreadsheet it had "Robot Check" but after the Working... message cleared (all formulas were updated) the item changed to _Im Full of Holiday Spirit Vodka and it's called T-Shirt_ so perhaps it was due to a number of calls or other item detected by Amazon?