# Import Amazon product Price and Title into Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to figure out "how to" import price and title for items sold on Amazon into a Google sheet. I'm using this amazon URL structure `https://www.amazon.com/dp/##########` and replacing the ###'s with the ASIN number for the product. I'd like that URL to be used to populate the Title and Price columns in the sheet linked below.

**Google Spreadsheet**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BkaKayngPkyfjOpzKRbYBAJAVWML9r3Fo-pN758CIrU/edit#gid=0

**Working Formula For Title**

```
=REGEXREPLACE(ImportXML("https://www.amazon.com/dp/"&B2,"//title"),"Amazon.com: ","")
```

**Tutorials Tested**

- [Use Google Sheets ImportXML with XPath to import Amazon product title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874770/use-google-sheets-importxml-with-xpath-to-import-amazon-product-title)
- [Amazon price in Google Spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004222/amazon-price-in-google-spreadsheets)

**I found this solution that proves it can be done, but it won't work for my use case.**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ETaMSeCpEUlWQsEXPfVkOC4faQBWMIMLEmculbH9wIg/edit#gid=1

**Product** - https://www.labnol.org/internet/amazon-price-tracker/28156/

Answer (score 4):

Grab it from another price website.

```
=importXml("https://camelcamelcamel.com/product/"&B2,"//span[@class='green']")
```